# String builder and String Concat

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

I have a piece of code that look follows this pattern ,

```
 var stringBuilder =new StringBuilder( string.Concat(" string", _variable, 
"another string" , _variable2 ... );
```

according to some logic do

```
stringBuilder.Append(" Some more strings");
```

I don't like The mismatch of using StringBuilder and string.Concat and I want a more elegant way of doing

What I thought was using StringBuilder.Append like so ,

```
StringBuilder.Append("string");
StringBuilder.Append(_variable);
StringBuilder.Append("another string");
```

Is there a better way then this approach ?

Comment: [StringBuilder.AppendFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.appendformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the `StringBuilder` is AFAIK the first BCL class that supports fluent syntax, so you can simply chain multiple `Append` / `AppendLine` / `AppendFormat` calls:

```
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder()
    .Append(" string").Append(_variable)
    .Append("another string").Append(_variable2)
    .Append(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# 6 you can use string interpolation:

```
var stringbuilder = new StringBuilder($"string{_variable}another string");
```

Comment: Or in < C# 6 you can use [string.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @KennethK. yes but the question stated specifically about no liking the mismatch

Comment: Perhaps, but using `string.Format` at least cleans up the string literal to be one string rather than 3+ strings.

Answer (score 0):

StringBuilder is the proper way to do a lot of string concatenation. It is specifically made for that and is optimal from performance point of view, so if you want a lot of string operations, use it. Otherwise if it's one small operation you can follow Matt Rowland advise (if you have C# 6), though you won't need StringBuilder for that at all:

```
string result = $"string {_variable} another string"
```

If you don't have C# 6, you can do:

```
string result = string.Format("string {0} another string", _variable)
```